# Akka Stream & Kamon-Prometheus not returning any metrics but loads an empty page

Tags: prometheus, akka-stream, kamon, akka-monitoring

I tried to integrate kamon-prometheus with akka stream project but at http://localhost:9095/ it loads an empty page.In the console I could see the message that metrics information is available at http://localhost:9095/.
When I tried with akka quickstart project, it worked fine.

Is kamon supported for akka streams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to run Main from Intellij and that was the reason why I did not get the metrics.With the suggestion from @Ivan Stanislavciuc , I tried `sbt run` and it worked.

Comment: It would be nice to give me some credit by upvoting my answer at least

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc Due to reputation being less than 15, I am not allowed to upvote :( .Sorry ,but I tried it and it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Answer (score 7):

Kamon uses aspecj heavily to gather some of the metrics. Please make sure that java agent aspectj-weaver is added to the boot of you JVM. See different options in this [documentation](https://kamon.io/docs/v1/guides/setting-up-the-agent/).

You also need to add dependencies to `build.sbt`

```scala
libraryDependencies += "io.kamon" %% "kamon-core" % "1.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "io.kamon" %% "kamon-prometheus" % "1.0.0"
```

Disable built-in server in `kamon-prometheus` by changing this setting key in `application.conf` file.

```scala
kamon.prometheus.start-embedded-http-server = no
```

Add `PrometheusReporter` to `Kamon`

```scala
    import kamon.Kamon
    import kamon.prometheus.PrometheusReporter
    
    private val reporter = new PrometheusReporter()
    private val registry = Kamon.addReporter(reporter)
```

And serve results of metrics with `akka-http` by defining a route and getting data from `reporter.scrapeData()`.

```scala
     val metrics = path("metrics") {
      encodeResponse {
        val prometheusContentType: ContentType.NonBinary = {
          ContentType.parse("text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8").right.get.asInstanceOf[ContentType.NonBinary]
        }
        Kamon.gauge("metrics_called").increment()
        complete(
          HttpResponse(
            status = StatusCodes.OK,
            entity = HttpEntity(prometheusContentType, reporter.scrapeData())
          )
        )
      }
    }
```

Or serve metrics to any incoming http request with code

```scala
    akka.http.scaladsl
      .Http(actorSystem)
      .bindAndHandleSync(
        _ => {
          Kamon.gauge("metrics_called").increment()
          HttpResponse(
            status = StatusCodes.OK,
            entity = HttpEntity(prometheusContentType, reporter.scrapeData())
          )
        },
        "0.0.0.0",
        9015
      )
```

In case if you receive blank page, make sure that `Kamon` gathers some metrics in the system. You could test this by adding `Kamon.gauge("metrics_called").increment()` into a http route for example.

Comment: Still it loads an empty page.

Comment: I tried that by adding Kamon.counter("app.orders.sent").increment() and I was able to see this with kamon-prometheus embedded server.

Comment: I have already added the below lines in plugins.sbt.                                                                                 
resolvers += Resolver.bintrayRepo("kamon-io", "sbt-plugins")
addSbtPlugin("io.kamon" % "sbt-aspectj-runner" % "1.1.0")

Comment: That was a really helpful point.I was doing run main all the time.And on doing sbt run , I think it will work.Now I am seeing some error in console.

Comment: No.I am using these libraries      .                                                           
  `"io.kamon" %% "kamon-core" % "1.0.0"`
  `"io.kamon" %% "kamon-logback" % "1.0.0"`
   `"io.kamon" %% "kamon-akka-2.5" % "1.0.1"`
   `"io.kamon" %% "kamon-prometheus" % "1.0.0"`